# Ошибка Spring Boot Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

в общем я пытаюсь получить данные с textaria в формате json отправить их в бд

```
@RestController
public class RESTCustCtrl {

@Autowired
private CustomerRepo customerRepo;

@RequestMapping(value = "sendStmt", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CustomerStatement custStmt(@RequestBody CustomerStatement customerStatement){
    customerRepo.save(customerStatement);
    return customerStatement;
}
}
```

получаю ошибку Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

если убираю аннотацию @RequestBody, а пишу

```
public @ResponceBody CustomerStatement custStmt(CustomerStatement customerStatement)
```

то получаю json со значениями полей 0 или non

```
@Entity
public class CustomerStatement {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private  long id;

private  String request;

private  float bid;

private Date due_date;

private  Boolean status = false;

public CustomerStatement(String request, float bid, Date due_date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.request = request;
    this.bid = bid;
    this.due_date = due_date;
    this.status = status;
}

public CustomerStatement(){}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setRequest(String request) {
    this.request = request;
}

public float getBid() {
    return bid;
}

public void setBid(float bid) {
    this.bid = bid;
}

public Date getDue_date() {
    return due_date;
}

public void setDue_date(Date due_date) {
    this.due_date = due_date;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84653/discussion-on-question-by-pa-tison--spring-boot-content-type-application).

Answer (score 3):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class RESTCustCtrl {

    private final CustomerRepo customerRepo;

    @Autowired
    public RESTCustCtrl(CustomerRepo customerRepo) {
        this.customerRepo = customerRepo;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/sendStmt")
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerStatement> custStmt(@RequestBody CustomerStatement customerStatement){
        customerRepo.save(customerStatement);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(customerStatement);
    }
}
```

Проверим правильность в POSTMAN:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, запрос выполнен успешно.

Не забудьте добавить аннотацию 
`@Table (name="имя таблицы")` в вашем ентити

Comment: Данное решение для `Media Type: application/json`, а вопрос про `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.